# Using wget -i with flags

Tags: wget

I want to start off by saying I am completely new to Ubuntu and still learning the commands.  With that said I couldn't find what I was looking for exactly and if I missed it, I'm sorry.

What I want to do is use wget to get multiple files, but at the same time I want to be able to rename each one.

I know I can use wget  -O  and it will download the individual file.  However, rather than copy/pasting this for each individual file I wanted a way to do multiple.

So I found I can do wget -i  and the file has all the links.

Basically this is command I am doing for one file.

```
wget --load-cookies=sitecookies.txt -r website/download/filepart1/ext -O filepart1ext
```

In this case filepart1 = first part of file name then a / followed by the extension so when it saves the file it only saves it as the ext name.  Example being video/mp4 gets saved as mp4 so I rename it to video.mp4

When I go to do this:

```
wget --load-cookies=sitecookies.txt -r urllist.txt
```

urllist contains:

```
site/download/video/mp4 -O video.mp4
site/download/video/mp5 -O video.mp5
```

It tells me the files don't exist, but if I remove the -O flag then it works.

Is it possible to list the url and use the -O flag and rename each?  Or is there a better way of doing this because I have no clue about Ubuntu anything.

Edit: (leaving above just in case)

This is the text I get when I do this command:

```
wget --load-cookies=sitecookies.txt -r urllist.txt
```

URL List has this as contents: (No -O flag)

```
https://example.com/download/exampletext/txt
```

Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2019-08-15 17:08:32--  https://example.com/download/exampletext/txt
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 94.23.231.237
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|94.23.231.237|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://takumi.example.com/download/6362 [following]
--2019-08-15 17:08:33--  https://takumi.example.com/download/6362
Resolving takumi.example.com (takumi.example.com)... 37.236.75.94
Connecting to takumi.example.com (takumi.example.com)|37.236.75.94|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 365414792 (348M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘example.com/download/exampletext/txt’

example.com/download/exampletext 100%[==========================================================================================================>] 348.49M  7.73MB/s    in 46s

This is what happens when I use the -O flag.

```
wget --load-cookies=sitecookies.txt -r urllist.txt
```

URL List has this as contents: (Has -O flag)

```
https://example.com/download/exampletext/txt -O exampletext.txt
```

Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2019-08-15 18:43:00--  https://example.com/download/exampletext/txt%20-O%20exampletext.txt
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 94.23.231.237
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|94.23.231.237|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-08-15 18:43:00 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: Doubt it. I would assume your rename needs a 2nd command. I tend to use python for this but someone is likely to come along and offer a bash method ;-)

Comment: Please [edit] and show us a full example of what you get from `wget -i`. It should be easy to loop over that file and download everything with a specific name, but I can't really help if you don't show what you have. If you show a real example (you can change the domain to `example.com` to avoid showing the actual URL, just keep the rest as is), I can give you a solution that extracts the desired name from what you have.

Comment: @terdon I updated the OP with what I think is the information you want? If not, let me know and I'll see what else I can do.